# iOS - Make child UIVewController background (of ContainerView) transparent

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, container-view, uicontainerview

I have created a ContainerView in my parentViewController and populated with childViewController.

I want the child childViewController background to be transparent. I have made it's view to be transparent, but it didn't help.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made the ContainerView background transparent.

Comment: Humm.. so its automatically take transparency os super view.